# Return value for opening non-existing file failing in C

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, return, return-value

I am currently working on a program and it's supposed to return 2 if the input file can't be opened or doesn't exist, but I'm getting a segmentation fault instead.
The existing input file already exists in my folder and it's supposed to be opened when its name is written as a parameter as shown in the code:

```
        int max_plateau = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < argc - 1 ; i++) {
            FILE *input = fopen(argv[i], "r");
            if (ferror(input)) {
                return 2;
            } else {
                read_file(input, &bridges, &count, max_plateau);
                if (max_plateau != 0) {
                    bridges[max_plateau - 1] += 1;
                    bridges[max_plateau] += 1;
                }
                max_plateau = count;
                fclose(input); 
            }
        }
```

The same goes for the output file

```
        if (argv[argc - 1] == NULL)
            return 2;
        else {
            int odd = 0;
            find_result(&ungerade, anzahl, &bruecken);
            FILE *output = fopen(argv[argc - 1], "w");
            if (ferror(output)) {
                if (bridges != NULL) {
                    free(bridges);
                }
                return 2;
            } else {
                print(output, odd, &bridges, count);
                fclose(output);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Keep in mind everything is working except the error cases, which are supposed to return 2.

Comment: What do you get if you try `ferror(NULL)`?  You need to check the value returned by `fopen`.

Answer (score 3):

Check the value returned by `fopen`:

```
FILE *input;
if( (input = fopen(argv[i], "r")) == NULL ){
    perror(argv[i]);
    return 2;
}
```

`ferror` is only used to check the error indicator on a file handle, which can be set if some operation on the handle fails.  Failing to open the file is not an operation on the file handle.  The file handle does not exist until `fopen` successfully creates it.  If the path does not exist (or any other condition prevents `fopen` from succeeding), `fopen` will return `NULL`.  It is invalid to pass `NULL` as an argument to `ferror`.

Answer (score 3):

`fopen()` returns a null pointer if it cannot open the file.

Calling `ferror()` with a null pointer causes undefined behavior as you observe.

`ferror()` cannot be used for this, this function accesses the error indicator in the `FILE` structure that may be set by an operation on the stream that fails. For example `getc()` returns `EOF` if the stream is at end of file or if there was some kind of error on the stream. Calling `ferror(file)` or `feof(file)` can help determine what happened, but these functions are almost never used. Calling `feof()` for anything else, such as before a file operation to test if the end of file has been reached **is a common mistake**.

Here is a modified version:

```
        int max_plateau = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < argc - 1 ; i++) {
            FILE *input = fopen(argv[i], "r");
            if (input == NULL) {
                return 2;
            } else {
                read_file(input, &bridges, &count, max_plateau);
                if (max_plateau != 0) {
                    bridges[max_plateau - 1] += 1;
                    bridges[max_plateau] += 1;
                }
                max_plateau = count;
                fclose(input); 
            }
        }

        [...]

        // The same fix for the output file

        if (argv[argc - 1] == NULL) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            int odd = 0;
            find_result(&ungerade, anzahl, &bruecken);
            FILE *output = fopen(argv[argc - 1], "w");
            if (output == NULL) {
                free(bridges);  // OK to call free with a null pointer
                return 2;
            } else {
                print(output, odd, &bridges, count);
                fclose(output);
                // should we free bridges?
            }
        }
```

Comment: Curious.  Why the `else` in `} else {` as `if()` block has  `return`?.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: the OP wrote it this way... I agree this style is questionable since the `else` branch does not end with a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

[`fopen()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) returns `NULL` when it failes, so you must check for it before passing the return value to `ferror()`.

In other words, you should use

```c
if(input == NULL || ferror(input))
```

instead of

```c
if(ferror(input))
```

(add check like this also for `output`)

Comment: Testing `ferror(input)` on a file that was just open is moot. Using `ferror()` is just a mistake here.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple, Please replace `ferror(input)` with `!file` while handling `fopen` error condition.

Comment: You may want to explain in a few words why OP's code is wrong and how your solution fixes the problem.

Comment: This actually removed the seg fault, but I'm still getting the wrong return value. How can I know what the return value is?